# How can I lower the volume of music playing in another app while my Text to Speech "talks"?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that uses Text To Speech, and also allows the user to call up their music player. [for now I'm trying to avoid coding my own player]
I would like to lower the volume or pause the music being play in the background [not my app] while my TTP is talking.

I was able to request sound focus using AudioManager just before my TTS, but then I don't know how to give it back. I have been searching for a while and I can't seem to get it right.

I appreciate any help you can give me, 
Thank you.

PS: I am aiming for Android version 2.2+

```
...
//Intent to load player    
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
...
//requesting focus
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

these are some of the links I have look and gotten me closer [I think]

- [fade in and out music while speaking a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043595/fade-in-and-out-music-while-speaking-a-text)
- http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html
- [Android launching music player using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent)

Answer (score 3):

> I was able to request sound focus using AudioManager just before my TTS, but then I don't know how to give it back.

Call [`abandonAudioFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#abandonAudioFocus%28android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener%29).

Comment: I think this where I am having problems. I missing something here. I don't know what to use for AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener. when using audioManager.requestAudioFocus I was able to "get away" will declaring that null. [I'm thinking it should be something else, but not sure what or how], Thanks! 
abandonAudioFocus (AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener l)

Comment: @Huasillo: You provide, to each of those, an instance of some object that implements the `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` interface. This is no different than how you handle any other listener in Android.

Comment: Thank you!!... I tried that before, but it was late at night, and I wasn't saving "AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener l" , this morning and after your comment, it worked. Much appreciated!

Comment: If I don't need to know when the focus is changed may I put null in the listener?

Comment: @melanke: I do not know -- I have not tried that. I would hope that it would work, but I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: Well I tested and its not throwing exceptions and working fine so far.